# Does a Timer object get automatically destroyed when the view controller is popped off the navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a Timer object to repeatedly execute some code for every second in one of the view controllers in my App. My question is will the system automatically invalidate the timer when I pop the view controller off the navigation stack? Somehow my intuition tells me that it doesn't because the timer object itself is not directly tied to the view controller object.

Edit Note: Below is the code for the VC swift file where the timer is created. Please don't bash me for my amateur code. So basically a VC of this type is created and gets pushed onto the navigation stack. Assuming a scenario where the user didn't press the pause button (in which case the timer is invalidated) before going back to the root view by pressing the back button on the navigation bar, will the timer object gets destroyed?

```
//
//  TimerViewController.swift
//  SwiftyTimer
//
//  Created by Jiaming Zhou on 5/6/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Jiaming Zhou. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class TimerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var countDownLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    private var timer: Timer?
    private var timePassed = -1
    private enum status {
        case ongoing
        case paused
        case completed
    }

    private enum buttonImage {
        case cancelButton
        case pauseButton
        case resumeButton
    }

    private var state = status.ongoing

    var activity: Activity?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let activity = activity {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: activity.name)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: activity.color)
        }

        //Start a timer that increments every second
        updateTimer()
        creatTimer()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            timePassed = -1
            timer?.invalidate()
            state = status.ongoing
            creatTimer()
            updateTimer()
        case 1:
            if state == status.ongoing {
                timer?.invalidate()
                timer = nil
                state = status.paused
                sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "\(buttonImage.resumeButton)"), for: .normal)
                sender.setTitle("Resume", for: .normal)
            } else if state == status.paused {
                creatTimer()
                state = status.ongoing
                sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "\(buttonImage.pauseButton)"), for: .normal)
                sender.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
            }
        default:
            return
        }
    }


}

//MARK: - Timer

extension TimerViewController {

    func creatTimer() {
        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
        self.timer = timer
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if let activity = activity {
            timePassed += 1

            if timePassed == activity.duration {
                self.timer?.invalidate()
                state = status.completed
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time's Up!", message: "you have completed your activity", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                present(alert, animated: true)
            }

            let currentTime = activity.duration - timePassed
            let hours = currentTime / 3600
            let minutes = (currentTime / 60) % 60
            let seconds =  currentTime % 60

            var countDown = ""
            if hours > 0 {
                countDown += "\(hours):"
            }
            if minutes > 9 {
                countDown += "\(minutes):"
            } else {
                countDown += "0\(minutes):"
            }
            if seconds > 9 {
                countDown += "\(seconds)"
            } else {
                countDown += "0\(seconds)"
            }

            countDownLabel.text = countDown
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: And something extra to consider: if the timer is still alive, it will also retain its target, meaning that the view controller won't get released from memory, even though you popped it from the stack. Which is a fun source of future bugs. Always invalidate your Timers when you are done with them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Timer` is not automatically invalidated because when you schedule it, the run loop is keeping a strong reference to it, regardless of whether the view controller has been dismissed or not. There are many ways to solve this, but two contemporary solutions include:

1. Use completion block `Timer`:

   - Use `[weak self]` pattern, so the timer won’t keep strong reference to `self`, thus breaking the strong reference cycle.
   - Have `deinit` method `invalidate` the timer when the view controller is deallocated.

   For example:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       weak var timer: Timer?

       override viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           createTimer()
       }

       deinit {
           timer?.invalidate()
       }

       func createTimer() {
           timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in            
               self?.handleTimer(timer)
           }
       }

       func handleTimer(_ timer: Timer) { ... }
   }
   ```

   Note, the `weak` declaration of the `timer` variable is unrelated to the breaking of the strong reference cycle, but rather serves another purpose, namely to ensure that when the timer is invalidated (should you `invalidate` it elsewhere), that the `timer` variable will automatically be set to `nil`. The key to breaking the strong reference cycle is the `[weak self]` in the timer’s closure.
2. The other approach is to use a GCD timer, which *will* be canceled when you remove your strong reference to it:

   - Again, use `[weak self]` pattern for the closure to avoid strong reference cycle.
   - But unlike `Timer`, a GCD timer does automatically stop when the `DispatchSourceTimer` reference is removed. So no `deinit` method to stop the dispatch timer is needed.

   Thus:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       private let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: .main)

       override viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           configureTimer()
       }

       func configureTimer() {
           timer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
               self?.handleTimer()
           }
           timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: 1)
           timer.resume()
       }

       func handleTimer() { ... }
   }
   ```

I’d generally use the `Timer` approach, but include the GCD `DispatchSourceTimer` for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The system won't automatically invalidate the timer. The view controller has no relation to the timer itself since the timer gets referenced (strongly) by the RunLoop object.

Apple's documentation also explicitly says that the only way to invalidate a timer is to actually call the method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415405-invalidate

> This method is the only way to remove a timer from an RunLoop object.
>   The RunLoop object removes its strong reference to the timer, either
>   just before the invalidate() method returns or at some later point.
>
> If it was configured with target and user info objects, the receiver
>   removes its strong references to those objects as well.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I guess I'll just create a custom left bar button to invoke the method. The only solution that I can think of right now.

Comment: @JiamingZhou - That’s not necessary. Just make sure that the timer doesn’t keep a strong reference to the view controller by using the closure-based rendition with `[weak self]` reference.

Comment: I don't understand why my answer was downvoted. The behavior of a "Timer" object regarding invalidation is quite clear regarding how it has to be manually invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also wrap it in a `class`, that will always `invalidate()` it when that class gets deinitialized:

```swift
class MortalTimer {
    private let timer: Timer

    init(
        withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval,
        repeats: Bool,
        block: @escaping (Timer) -> Void
    ) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
            withTimeInterval: refreshPeriod, 
            repeats: true,
            block: block
        )
    }

    deinit {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```